# Socket application

Tags: c#, sockets

my software consists of two parts. one of them is client, i can connect my device on router via ethernet and i can send a command ( data ) then i am starting to wait getting response from my device, but i cannot figure out how i could get responce, despite of the fact that i have been looking for similar socket application. i have studying c# for 2 weeks. Would you help me about this topic ?

If you can help me, i will be really pleasure you.

```
namespace sencron_socket
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket sck;
        static Socket scks;
        static byte[] Buffer { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPEndPoint localendpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.204.101"), 50007); //50007  bidirectional interface The event 


        try
        {
            sck.Connect(localendpoint);

            if (sck.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectWrite))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this socket is writable");
            }

            else if (sck.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectError))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this socket has an error");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write(" unable ");
            Main(args);
        }




        Console.Write("enter text:  ");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

        sck.Send(data);
        Console.Write(" data sent! \r\n   ");
        //Console.Write(" press ant key to continue  ");

       // Console.Read();
        sck.Close();

            scks = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

           scks.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.204.104"),0));

           scks.Listen(1);

             Console.Write(" it is ok until this step ");

          // ???????????????????????????????????????????????????????
           // i think that my problem starts next line with Accept()  


             Socket accepted = scks.Accept();
             Console.Write(" BURDA 222 \r\n");
             IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)accepted.RemoteEndPoint;

             Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
             int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);
             byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];

            /* for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
             {
                 formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
             }*/

             Console.Write(" BURDA 3333 ");
             string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
             Console.Write(strData + "\r\n");

             scks.Close();
             accepted.Close();

             Console.Read();


    }
}
}
```

Comment: you don't need to close the socket after your initial connection and write, just start reading & waiting for data...  2 weeks of c#?  pretty good for a newbie..

Comment: Of course you will need to close after you are done using the socket.

Comment: To really know what you should be doing, you'd need to post the server code that you are initially connecting to but it seems like you are trying to write something that connects, writes and waits for a response.  That all can be done with the original socket.

Comment: thank you so much Mr T McKeown,

Comment: I think that I understood a little bit and i will try your suggestion. By the way, you are  so kind. thanks a lot again. Have a nice day and working.